# Is there a use for a delegate type that returns a delegate of the same type as itself?

Tags: c#, delegates, functional-programming

I was fiddling around in Visual Studio and I discovered that

```
delegate RecursiveDelegate RecursiveDelegate();
```

is a valid delegate definition.

I don't have a great deal of functional programming experience, but I was wondering if this pattern is ever actually useful in functional programming, or if its just a curiosity of semantics.  I want to ask this question in two ways:

1. In a context with side effects.  I can see this actually being a half-way decent way to model iteratively learning algorithms in a functional language, where the actual task of the algorithm is performed as a side effect, and the new version of the function is the return value.  Is this done?
2. In a context without side effects.  I think that this in principle useless, but I'm super curious if I'm wrong.  Can this be useful if we assume that the implementation of RecursiveDelegate() has no side effects?

Comment: In the CLR, a delegate is an object that has an `Invoke` method (with some additional metadata, but that's the core of it). If you think of it that way, there's nothing strange with the fact that it works. It's nothing weirder than an object that returns itself in a method.

Comment: @zneak - I don't think the question is about why it works (somewhat reasonable as function can return any type it wants), but rather how/if it can be useful for functional style of programming.

Comment: Of course. That's why I'm not posting an answer. I was addressing the initial surprise expressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a potentially useful pattern for a state machine:

```
delegate State State();

State state = MainMenu;

while (state != null) // or have a 'pump' call each update
{
   state = state();
}

State MainMenu()
{
   if (playPressed) return StartLevelOne();
   return MainMenu;
}

State StartLevelOne()
{
   //set up level
   return LevelOne;   // or LevelOne() if you want an immediate update
}

State LevelOne()
{
    //check for level one ending
    return LevelOne;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an example of some similar code that isn't exactly a recursive delegate, but it comes close. A "Y-Combinator" comes close - and quite frankly I have no idea how it works in practice, but it is used to define recursive functions.

Here's the funky code you need to define:

```
public delegate T S<T>(S<T> s);

public static T U<T>(S<T> s)
{
    return s(s);
}

public static Func<A, Z> Y<A, Z>(Func<Func<A, Z>, Func<A, Z>> f)
{
    return U<Func<A, Z>>(r => a => f(U(r))(a));
}
```

Now you can define recursive functions in one line.

Factorial:

```
var fact = Y<int, int>(_ => x => x == 0 ? 1 : x * _(x - 1));
var fact5 = fact(5); // == 120
var fact6 = fact(6); // == 720
var fact7 = fact(7); // == 5040
```

Fibonacci:

```
var fibo = Y<int, int>(_ => x => x <= 1 ? 1 : _(x - 1) + _(x - 2));
var fibo5 = fibo(5); // == 8
var fibo6 = fibo(6); // == 13
var fibo7 = fibo(7); // == 21
```

My favourite line in the code is the call `s(s)`. Seriously, if anyone can straighten that out in the head they're a genius! Let alone the whole `U<Func<A, Z>>(r => a => f(U(r))(a))`.